# Media keys to control only iTunes in windows 10

Tags: windows, itunes, media

I have a [Logitech MX Master](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024154914) mouse and have assigned media commands (play/pause, next, previous...etc) to the buttons of the mouse.

However, any time iTunes is not the window in focus, I can't use the media controls. Is there any way to use these controls even when i am using another app but iTunes is still open in the background? Or is there any way to make the media controls specific to just iTunes and no other apps?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use the [SetPoint software](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025141274), which can be configured to use a global setup of key-mappings and/or to set specific key-combinations for each program (like iTunes).

The specific combinations override the general ones, so you should have no problems if you configure it in the right way.

Comment: The mx master mouse uses logitech's alternate software called logitech options. Setpoint does not recognise my mouse. I have mapped the buttons on my mouse using logitech options and it still doesn't work unless itunes is the window in focus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: That's disappointing. I use a Logitech mouse myself, and SetPoint worked as expected (As long as I used Windows).